# Transparent NSWindow + custom NSView - don't want custom drawn objects to cast shadows?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

So I have a borderless window with it's background color set to clear. Inside it, I have an NSView with some custom drawing. It looks like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/16dh9ez3z04eic7/Screenshot%202016-02-10%2012.15.35.png?dl=0

The problem is, the custom drawing is casting a shadow, which you can see if the view is hidden:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/04ymp0b2yqi5egu/Screenshot%202016-02-10%2012.19.04.png?dl=0

I only want the shadow around the frame of the window! How can I achieve this?

NOTE: strangely enough, giving the window a title bar provides the behavior I want: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1vv9iwb5403tufe/Screenshot%202016-02-10%2012.25.29.png?dl=0 - Unfortunately, I don't want a title bar.

The code:

```
@implementation MyWindow

/*
 In Interface Builder, the class for the window is set to this subclass. Overriding the initializer
 provides a mechanism for controlling how objects of this class are created.
 */
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
                styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle
                  backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
                    defer:(BOOL)flag {

    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:bufferingType defer:NO];

    if (self != nil) {
        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];

        [self makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
        [self setMovable:YES];
        [self setShowsResizeIndicator:YES];
        [self setResizeIncrements:NSMakeSize(2, 2)];
        [self setLevel:TOP_LEVEL];
    }
    return self;
}

/*
 Custom windows that use the NSBorderlessWindowMask can't become key by default. Override this method
 so that controls in this window will be enabled.
 */
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

And the ContentView:

```
@implementation WindowContentView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    // we need to redraw the whole frame
    dirtyRect = self.bounds;

    // background
    NSBezierPath *framePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:dirtyRect xRadius:0.0f yRadius:0.0f];
    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:0.3f] setFill];
    [framePath fill];

    // border
    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] setStroke];
    framePath.lineWidth = 1.0f;
    [framePath stroke];

    // grid
    [self drawGridInRect:dirtyRect];

    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}

- (void)drawGridInRect:(NSRect)rect {
    int rows = 5;
    int columns = 5;

    float gridWidth = CGRectGetWidth(rect)/columns;
    float gridHeight = CGRectGetHeight(rect)/rows;

    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:153.0f/255.0f alpha:0.2f] setStroke];
    [NSBezierPath setDefaultLineWidth:1.0f];

    for(int i=1; i<rows; i++) {
        [NSBezierPath strokeLineFromPoint:NSMakePoint(gridWidth*i, CGRectGetMaxY(rect))
                                  toPoint:NSMakePoint(gridWidth*i, CGRectGetMinY(rect))];
    }

    for(int i=1; i<columns; i++) {
        [NSBezierPath strokeLineFromPoint:NSMakePoint(CGRectGetMaxX(rect), gridHeight*i)
                                  toPoint:NSMakePoint(CGRectGetMinX(rect), gridHeight*i)];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: How are you drawing the custom view inside the window?

Comment: @rocky, I set the contentView of the window to my own NSView subclass. Then in that subclass, I override the drawRect method.

Comment: Would you like to share some of that code?

Comment: @rocky added some code!